# Can we prove that the solutions of $\int_0^y \sin(\sin(x)) dx =1$ are irrational?

Tags: calculus, integration, roots, irrational-numbers

Can we prove that the solutions of $$\int_0^y \sin(\sin(x)) dx =1$$ are irrational? Wolfram Alpha gives two *approximate* sets of solutions as $\{4.58+2\pi k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{1.69+2\pi k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Can we prove they are irrational?

Comment: Doesn't this follow immediately from the fact that $\pi$ is irrational?

Comment: @dleggas Oh, how?

Comment: A rational number times an irrational is always irrational. Then an irrational number plus a rational number is also irrational

Comment: @dleggas $4.58$ and $1.69$ are just approximations, I doubt that the actual values would be rational at all! You can try it on WA.

Comment: I edited your post slightly because your upper limit of integration was the same as your integration variable. I hope this does not change what you meant in your post.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, no problem, thanks :)

Comment: A line of attack ? Consider the inverse function of the square root of the integral, and find its McLaurin development around $0$. (The square root is to avoid an infinite slope at the origin.) My guess is that all derivatives yield an integer value. By evaluating the series at $1$, you'll get (hopefully convergent) rational approxiamtions.

Comment: One could also ask the following question, which seems to me just as interesting: Suppose we consider a variety of 'target values' on the RHS. Are there cases with rational $y$?

Comment: The two solutions in $[0,2\pi]$ sum to $2\pi$ due to symmetry, $f(\pi+t)=f(\pi-t)$. Moreover, the Taylor series of the inverse function of $f$ has the form $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}q_n x^{(2n+1)/2}$$ where all the $q_n$s are rational numbers. This brings the approximation $\zeta_0\approx\frac{6043}{2520\sqrt{2}}$, for instance, but it looks really hard to find useful arithmetic informations for such coefficients.

Comment: I would try to understand if the inverse function can be expressed as a generalized continued fraction with rational terms by checking if $f^{-1}(x)$ satisfies a good-looking second-order differential equation, just to mimic the continued fraction proof of the irrationality of $e$. I do not really believe this will happen, however.

Comment: The first continued fraction approximation for $f^{-1}(x)$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{1-x/6}$ and the second one is $\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{1-\frac{x}{6-\frac{x}{10}}}$ that leads to the pretty good approximation $\zeta_0\approx\frac{59}{49}\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some partial progress towards the desired integral.

The [Jacobi-Anger expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi-Anger_expansion) provides a direct line of attack. The Fourier series of $\sin( z\sin (x))$ is
$$\sin(z \sin(x)) = 2\sum_{k\text{ odd}}^\infty J_{k}(z)\sin kx$$ where $J_k(x)$ is a Bessel function of order $k$. Hence we may immediately integrate, obtaining

\begin{align}
I_z(y)\equiv \int_0^y \sin(z \sin(x))\,dx
&=2\sum_{k\text{ odd}}^\infty J_k(z) \int_0^y \sin kx \,dx\\
&=\sum_{k\text{ odd}}^\infty \frac{4}{k}J_k(z)\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}k y\right)
\end{align}
(As an aside, for small $y$ this gives $I_z(y)\approx Cy^2$ with $C=\sum_{k\text{ odd}}^\infty k\,J_k(z).$)

Hence the question has been converted to a summation problem; more specifically, this is a Neumann series expansion for $I_z(y)$.  (The Jacobi-Anger expansion was this kind of series as well.) The question is then how one proceeds further, with the goal of finding roots in the special case $I(1;y)=1$. Does anyone see a path forward?