# Series involving modified Bessel functions of half integer order

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I am interested in computing a closed-form for the infinite series
$$ \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} \left( I_{k - \frac{1}{2}} \left( z \right) + I_{k + \frac{1}{2}} \left( z \right) \right) \cos{\left( 2 k \theta \right)} , $$
for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, $z > 0$, and where $I_n$ is the modified Bessel function of order $n$. I would also be happy to know closed-forms for the special cases
$$ \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} \left( I_{k - \frac{1}{2}} (x) + I_{k + \frac{1}{2}} (x) \right) , $$
and
$$ \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2} \left( I_{k - \frac{1}{2}} (x)  + I_{k + \frac{1}{2}} (x) \right) , $$
which corresponded to $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi / 2$, respectively.

The derivative of the original series with respect to $\theta$ appears related to the
[Jacobi-Anger](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.35) relations, but the half integral order prevents a direct adaptation. This question also seems related: [Sum of Bessel functions and integral of exponential of sine or cosine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975117/sum-of-bessel-functions-and-integral-of-exponential-of-sine-or-cosine). I am thinking the series could be related to $e^{z \cosh{ \theta }}$ or $e^{z \sinh{ \theta }}$ since $I_{k \pm 1/2} (z)$ is are related to $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: Try transforming the half integer Bessel functions into their spherical forms since those have half integer orders for all integers. Also, half integer order Bessel functions are always elementary special cases.